# AngularJS ng-repeat with nested json

Tags: angularjs, json

my json look like below

```
$scope.peoples = [people:{
    name: 'Mike ',
    age: 20
}, people:{
    name: 'Peter S ',
    age: 22
}];
```

**Notes: i can not change json structure.**

here is my code where `ng-repeat` could not read `json`.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="p in peoples">
            <td> Name: {{ p.name }} &nbsp;</td>
            <td> Age: {{ p.age }} &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.peoples = [people:{
        name: 'Mike ',
        age: 20
    }, people:{
        name: 'Peter S ',
        age: 22
    }];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this "**i can not change json structure**", if you do in the console `var a = [people:{
    name: 'Mike ',
    age: 20
}, people:{
    name: 'Peter S ',
    age: 22
}];` you get **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :(…)**. It's like expecting `if x == 3 > 4` to work because you can't change the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your json array is defined in wrong way:

```
$scope.peoples = [{
        name: 'Mike ',
        age: 20
    },{
        name: 'Peter S ',
        age: 22
    }];
```

notice there is no people object.  you defined people without an object.  If you fix your json your code will work fine.

Here's the working code with json fix : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2236/

Other way of fixing the existing code with the people object is, you move the people in javascript object as shown below:

Javascript:

```
$scope.peoples = [{
    people : {
        name: 'Mike ',
        age: 20
    }},{
    people: {
        name: 'Peter S ',
        age: 22
    }}];
```

Html:

```
  <td> Name: {{ p.people.name }} &nbsp;</td>
  <td> Age: {{ p.people.age }} &nbsp;</td>
```

This way your can use the people object. Here's the working code : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2237/

Overall, i would recommend using first approach instead of second one.

Comment: i know if i remove people then it would work. but in your js fiddle u did not use  p.people.name. so please use it in jsfiddle.

Comment: see your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2238/  not working when i use `p.people.name`

Comment: checkout 2nd solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2237/ 
you need to defined people under object for angular ng-repeat to understand.